# how to show "Yes/No" CGridView yii depending on the flag field 0/1?

Tags: php, yii

I am stuck in a problem in CGridView yii, my refund field show 0/1 but I want to show "Yes" if 0 and "No" if 1, without using any second table.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'transaction-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'member_id',
     array(
        'header' => 'MemberName',
        'name' => 'member_id',
        'value' => '$data->member->f_name'
    ),

    'refund',
    'band_id',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
```

));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 array(
                    'name' => 'refund',
                    'header' => "Refund",
                    'value' => '$data->refund?Yii::t(\'app\',\'Yes\'):Yii::t(\'app\', \'No\')',
                    'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'No'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Yes')),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "text-align:center;"),
              ),
```

Comment: I get the following error: `include($data->approved?Yii::t('app','Yes'):Yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

Comment: you should check why your scripts composes that ugly filename that is some kind of php code.

Comment: better/complete answer below

Answer (score 19):

Both of the other answers will work, but the cleanest way to do it is:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'member_id',

    ...

    'refund:boolean',
),
```

There are a bunch of CGridView column data types that are auto-used if you use colons like above. More info here: https://github.com/samdark/a-guide-to-yii-grids-lists-and-data-providers/blob/master/grid-columns.md

Comment: Thanks! That link is very useful. Options are: date, time, datetime, number, email, url, image, raw, text, ntext, and html.

Comment: Pentium got his answer in (and accepted) before I wrote mine the next day ;-)

Comment: Certainly a better answer. Using a anon function for the value is very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will solve your problem.

Replace "refund" with this code.

```
 array(
            'header' => 'Refund',
            'name' => 'refund',
            'value' => '($data->refund == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"'
        ),
```

Comment: For me, this displays `($data->refund == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"`, so not the actual value Yes or No.

Answer (score 2):

When displaying a boolean field in a [`CGridView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail) use the `name:type:header` format when creating the columns to specify the type as boolean. E.g.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    ...
    'columns'=>array(
       'id',
       'refund:boolean',
),
```

If you want to change the way the field is displayed in a [`CActiveForm`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm) change the render method to use either a checkbox or a dropdown list. My preference is dropdown list because it gives you the option of setting the value back to null.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'refund', array(null=>"Not checked", 0=>"No", 1=>"Yes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:
Replace `'refund',` with:

```
        array(
        'name' => 'refund',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => function($model){
            return $model->refund == 1 ? 'No' : 'Yes';
        }
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

IN  VIEWS NAMES ADMIN.PHP

> array(
>               'name'=>'status',
>               'header'=>'status',
>               'filter'=>array('1'=>'Inacive','2'=>'Active'),
>               'value'=>'($data->status=="1")?("Inacive"):("Active")'
>           ),